# Link resolving error while modifying ionic angular tabs seed app

Tags: angular-ui, ionic-framework

I am trying to modify the ionic angular seed application to suit my purpose. I am using links `<a>` with button definition for navigation. But the link is not resolving to the required view. Webstorm IDE throws the below error:

`Cannot resolve anchor #/tab/deals in file tab-dash.html`

The link is written as below:

```
[ open a tag ] 
class="button button-outline button-calm" style="width: 48%;" href="#/tab/deals" >
          Queries
[closing a tag]
```

and the relevant state routing code from App.js  is as below.

```
.state('tab.deals', {
  url: '/deals',
  views: {
    'tab-deals': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-deals.html',
      controller: 'dealsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

It used to work when it was in the footer tab section. But not working when I moved it to main section under `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`

Comment: I realize from a codepen example that in a tabbed app all the navigatiion is locked to the tabs as in Tab - Nav View - View. So my link did not work because i had removed the respective tab link - since it looked redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Webstorm however, you can use [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-sref) directive in its place. 
Replace the path name with the name of the state you want to navigate to:

```
<a class="button button-outline button-calm" 
   style="width: 48%;"
   ui-sref="tab.deals">Queries</a>
```